# pass the argument from one method to another method in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, parameter-passing

This is my view part

Ext.define('A2a.view.act.Job', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',

```
requires: [
    'A2a.store.Job',
    'A2a.store.SharedData',
],

border: false,
chart: null,




hrer: [],
layout: {type: 'vbox', pack: 'start', align: 'stretch'},



initComponent: function () {
    var me = this;


    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: utils.createUrl('api', 'dashboard-read'),
        async: true,

        callback: function(opts, success, response) {
            try {

                if (success) {
                    var output = App.decodeHttpResp(response.responseText);
                    const data = output.data;


                    var myArr = [];
                    data.map((date) => 
                    myArr = Object.keys(date).filter(key => key != 'DATE'));
                    me.hrer =myArr;

                    console.log(me.hrer =myArr);

                    me.loadChart();
                    //me.loadww();

                } 
            } catch (ex) {
                //return ex;
            }
        }
    });



   this.loadww();
    this.loadData(me.hrer);

    me.callParent(arguments);


},
loadData : function () {
    console.log("Init Function");
},







loadww: function (hrer) {
    var me = this;
    //var self = this;
    console.log(me.hrer);
    me.jobStore = Ext.create('O2a.store.PendingReports');
    Ext.apply(me, {
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'chart',
                itemId: 'charid',
                name: 'charid',
                store : new Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
                        proxy: {
                            type: 'ajax',
                            url : utils.createUrl('api', 'dashboard-read'),
                            reader: {
                                type: 'json',
                                root: 'data'
                            }
                        },
                        autoLoad : true,
                        successProperty : 'success',

                        fields : [{name: 'DATE', type: 'auto'}].concat(

    O2a.store.SharedData.hrer.map(function(companyName) {
        console.log(companyName);
        return {
            name: companyName,
            type: 'int'
        };
    })
)
                    }),
                style: 'background: #fff',
                insetPadding: 40,
                animate: true,
                shadow: false,
                flex: 2,
                minHeight: 300,
                legend: {
                    position: 'top',
                    boxStrokeWidth: 0,
                    labelFont: '12px Helvetica'
                },

                axes: [{
                        type: 'Numeric',
                        position: 'left',
                        fields: ['1'],
                        grid: true,
                        minimum: 0,

                    }, {
                        type: 'Category',
                        position: 'bottom',
                        fields: ['DATE'],
                        grid: true,
                    }],

            }]
    });
},



loadChart: function (hrer) {

    var me = this;
    console.log(me.hrer);
var cha = this.down('#charid');
var iii = null;
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: utils.createUrl('api', 'dashboard-read'),
        async: true,

        callback: function(opts, success, response) {
            try {

                if (success) {
                    var output = App.decodeHttpResp(response.responseText);
                    const data = output.data;

                    me.hrer
                    let myArr = [];
                    data.map((date) => 
                    myArr = Object.keys(date).filter(key => key != 'DATE'));


cha.series.clear();
    for(var i=0;i<myArr.length;i++){

    cha.series.add({           
    type: 'line',
    axis: 'left',
    xField: 'DATE',
    border: false,
    flex: 1,
    title: myArr[i],
    yField: myArr[i],       
    markerConfig: {
        radius: 4
    },
    highlight: {
        fill: '#000',
        radius: 5,
        'stroke-width': 2,
        stroke: '#fff'
    },

    tips: {
        trackMouse: true,
        style: 'background: #FFF',
        height: 20,
        width: 120,

        renderer: function (storeItem, item) {
            var name = item.series.title[Ext.Array.indexOf(item.series.yField, item.yField)];
            this.setTitle(name + ': ' + storeItem.get(item.yField));
        }
    }


    });
}
            } else {
                    //return 'Unknown Reason';
                }
            } catch (ex) {
                //return ex;
            }
        }
    });
```

}

}
);

I want to pass the hrer inside the loadww method. If I call the loadww inside the callback of initcomponent function I can be able to pass it. But the graph is not loading. If I call it after the ajax request the graph is loading, but can't pass the hrer to outside.
How to pass the hrer array inside the loadww function. Thanks in advance

Comment: If loadww requires the data populated in hrer by the request callback, then calling it immediately after Ext.Ajax.request will not work.  This is because the request is asynchronous, so loadww is guaranteed to be called before the request callback is executed. Therefore, loadww needs to be called from the callback. However, the code provided is incomplete, so I can't say why the graph does not load.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have edited my post with full codes. Could you please guide me why the graph is not loading. I have tried. But couldn't. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From the style of the code it looks like this is ExtJS 3.x
In Ext.Ajax.request define the scope with this to stay in the view.

Your code is not in the best shape.

- get rid of the try...catch.
- try to write success: this.dashboardSuccess
- using callback, will run in both cases (success, failure)

If this is ExtJS 4+ you should split your code in MVC

If this is ExtJS 6+ you should split your code in MVVM

- write your code declarative
- out the stores in VM and use the load-Event
- do not use initComponent
- use data-binding